# Bokeh line plot connects every points to the first point, what is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, windows-10, bokeh

I'm trying to feed live data and plot it against datetime. However every point is connected to the first point by a line. What is wrong here? Thank you for any help.
(I saved this as `test.py` and ran `bokeh serve --show test.py` in the command prompt.)

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import numpy as np

x, y = [], []
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=x, data=y))

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='time', y='data', source=source)
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%m/%d %H:%M", months="%m/%d %H:%M",
                                          hours="%m/%d %H:%M", minutes="%m/%d %H:%M")


def update():
    x.append(np.datetime64('now'))
    y.append(np.random.rand())
    source.stream(dict(time=x, data=y), 100)


curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)
curdoc().title = "random"
```

It looks like something shown below:
[image]

Comment: @bigreddot, thanks for your reply. As you can see, it's a live data genrated inside the code from time-0. There is no other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stream` is for adding *new* points to a data source. You are continually accumulating *all* points from every update, and thus re-streaming old points you have already been sent. There is no need to append anything, send only the actual new points, and nothing else:

```
def update():
    x = [np.datetime64('now')]
    y = [np.random.rand()]
    source.stream(dict(time=x, data=y), 100)
```